# Open link in twitter

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

How to scraping the link such as http://bitly.is/heretohelp in tweet and then open the link automatically?

Comment: The question is not clear. are you trying to scrape Twitter and open links from it?

Comment: Yes @SumitJaiswal

Comment: Another question, by opening the links do you mean saving them somewhere or scrape those links?

Comment: @SumitJaiswal Scrape those links. After we got the link, and open it automatically

Comment: @SumitJaiswal just like my example first we scrape the tweet that contains bit.ly and then we can automatically open the link that we already scrape

Comment: Please share your code/approach. Try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013072/extracting-external-links-from-tweets-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy gives you access to the Tweet text and conveniently exposing the urls, hashtags, for example to get the URLs within a Tweet:

```
tweet = api.get_status(id='000001')

print(tweet.entities['urls'])
for url in tweet.entities['urls']:
  # t.co url
  print(url['url'])
  # original url
  print(url['expanded_url'])
```

Once you have the URLs you can decide to do what you want (scrape the target url or open in a browser tab - if you have a web app for example)